# How to get items from database with http protocol in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, http

I'm trying to get info from my db using http get method, but when I try to get data, it returns the error:

> E/flutter (15407): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(198)] Unhandled Exception: type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'int' of 'index'

Here is the code:

```
// ignore_for_file: no_leading_underscores_for_local_identifiers, prefer_typing_uninitialized_variables

import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:apetit_project/models/app_user.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import '../models/auth_form_data.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

class AuthForm extends StatefulWidget {
  final void Function(AuthFormData) onSubmit;

  const AuthForm({
    Key? key,
    required this.onSubmit,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<AuthForm> createState() => _AuthFormState();
}

class _AuthFormState extends State<AuthForm> {
  TextEditingController _emailController = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController _passwordController = TextEditingController();
  final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  final _formData = AuthFormData();
  String _teste = '[]';
  final _url = 'http://172.16.30.120:8080/ords/apiteste/integrafoods/users';

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _emailController.dispose();
    _passwordController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  bool isLogin = true;
  late String title;
  late String actionButton;
  late String toggleButton;

  void _submit() {
    final isValid = _formKey.currentState?.validate() ?? false;
    if (!isValid) return;

    widget.onSubmit(_formData);
  }

  Future<void> _loadUsers() async {
    final response = await http.get(Uri.parse(_url));
    Map<String, dynamic> data = jsonDecode(response.body);
    data.forEach(
      (userId, userData) {
        _teste = userData['nome'];
      },
    );
    print(_teste);

    // $_url/${newComment.comment}
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        decoration: const BoxDecoration(
          image: DecorationImage(
            image: AssetImage('assets/images/Login.png'),
            fit: BoxFit.cover,
            alignment: Alignment.center,
          ),
        ),
        child: Container(
          margin: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 30),
          child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20),
            child: Form(
              key: _formKey,
              child: Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                children: [
                  if (_formData.isSignup)
                    TextFormField(
                      key: const ValueKey('Nome'),
                      initialValue: _formData.name,
                      onChanged: (name) => _formData.name = name,
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                        enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                            borderSide: const BorderSide(color: Colors.black),
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30)),
                        focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                            borderSide: const BorderSide(color: Colors.black),
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30)),
                        focusedErrorBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                            borderSide: const BorderSide(color: Colors.black),
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30)),
                        labelText: 'Nome',
                        labelStyle: const TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
                      ),
                      keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
                    ),
                  if (_formData.isLogin)
                    TextFormField(
                      // controller: _emailController,
                      key: const ValueKey('Email'),
                      initialValue: _formData.email,
                      onChanged: (email) => _formData.email = email,
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                        enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                            borderSide: const BorderSide(color: Colors.black),
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30)),
                        focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                            borderSide: const BorderSide(color: Colors.black),
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30)),
                        focusedErrorBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                            borderSide: const BorderSide(color: Colors.black),
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30)),
                        prefixIcon: Image.asset(
                          'assets/images/email_icon.png',
                          scale: 6,
                          color: Colors.black,
                        ),
                        labelText: 'Email',
                        labelStyle: const TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
                      ),
                      validator: (_email) {
                        final email = _email ?? '';
                        if (!email.contains('@')) {
                          return 'E-mail informado não é válido.';
                        }
                        return null;
                      },
                      keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
                    ),
                  const SizedBox(
                    height: 20,
                  ),
                  if (_formData.isLogin)
                    TextFormField(
                      // controller: _passwordController,
                      key: const ValueKey('password'),
                      initialValue: _formData.password,
                      onChanged: (password) => _formData.password = password,
                      style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
                      obscureText: true,
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                          enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                              borderSide: const BorderSide(color: Colors.black),
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30)),
                          focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                              borderSide: const BorderSide(color: Colors.black),
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30)),
                          errorBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                              borderSide: const BorderSide(color: Colors.black),
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30)),
                          focusedErrorBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                              borderSide: const BorderSide(color: Colors.black),
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30)),
                          prefixIcon: Padding(
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 18, right: 18),
                            child: Image.asset(
                              'assets/images/password_icon.png',
                              scale: 6,
                              color: Colors.black,
                            ),
                          ),
                          labelText: 'Senha',
                          labelStyle: const TextStyle(color: Colors.black)),
                      validator: (_password) {
                        final password = _password ?? '';
                        if (password.length < 6) {
                          return 'Senha deve ter no mínimo 6 caracteres';
                        }
                        return null;
                      },
                    ),
                  const SizedBox(
                    height: 20,
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    width: double.infinity,
                    child: ElevatedButton(
                      // onPressed: _signInUser,
                      onPressed: _loadUsers,
                      style: ButtonStyle(
                        shape: MaterialStateProperty.all(RoundedRectangleBorder(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30),
                        )),
                        padding:
                            MaterialStateProperty.all(const EdgeInsets.all(15)),
                        backgroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.all(
                            Theme.of(context).colorScheme.secondary),
                      ),
                      child: Text(
                        _formData.isLogin ? 'Entrar' : 'Cadastrar',
                        style: const TextStyle(
                            color: Colors.black,
                            fontFamily: 'Raleway',
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  TextButton(
                    onPressed: () {
                      setState(() {
                        _formData.toggleAuthMode();
                      });
                    },
                    child: Text(
                      _formData.isLogin
                          ? 'Criar uma nova conta?'
                          : 'Já possui conta?',
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Future _signInUser() async {
    await FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithEmailAndPassword(
      email: _emailController.text,
      password: _passwordController.text,
    );
  }
}
```

```
{
    "items": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "login": "1234567",
            "nome": "Ricardo",
            "situacao": "A",
            "telefone": "(14) 99797-5621",
            "senha": "124578",
            "dt_inclusao": null,
            "usu_inclusao": null,
            "dt_alteracao": null,
            "usu_alteracao": null
        }
    ],
    "hasMore": false,
    "limit": 25,
    "offset": 0,
    "count": 1,
    "links": [
        {
            "rel": "self",
            "href": "http://172.16.30.120:8080/ords/apiteste/integrafoods/users"
        },
        {
            "rel": "describedby",
            "href": "http://172.16.30.120:8080/ords/apiteste/metadata-catalog/integrafoods/item"
        },
        {
            "rel": "first",
            "href": "http://172.16.30.120:8080/ords/apiteste/integrafoods/users"
        }
    ]
}
```

I added the full widget code and the JSON. I am seeking a working example so I can understand why it's not working.

Comment: The exception says it all. userData is a List, you are trying to access it via a String. This does not work.

Comment: Can you provide full code and datas snippet?

Answer (score 0):

It's look like you have in userDat variable some sort of List. It dosen't have key:value pair like Map. Yo need to run through List indexes.
Try to use

```
    _teste = userData[0]['nome'];
```

And look what happens.
You need to look on JSON structure you receive from the server. If you show here JSON structure it will help to find right solution for you.